# Accessing HTML custom attributes

Tags: html, custom-attributes

I want to know is there any way to add a custom attribute to the a
HTML element.

For example ,

```
<input type="text" name="txtNAME1" displayName="dname1" />
```

In the above example the custom attribute **"displayName"** is not a
standard HTML attribute. So  I want to know if I can define the same and push the intended value to the server and access the same attribute's value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which language are you using? You can do this in C# using

```
<input type="text" name="txtNAME1" displayName="dname1" runat="server" id="test" />
```

Then, in the code behind:

```
test.Attributes["displayName"];
```

You can also access it in jQuery with

```
$('test').attr('displayName')
```

and send it through to the server via a handler.

Comment: Thanks Thedixon, well i want to implement this in ruby. Will try this if it works as well.. :)